# Bluetooth-lowenergy (BLE) in background comunication with IONIC

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, multiplatform

The application has to connect with a BLE device when it’s nearby and needs to retrieve data periodically. All this even when the application is not running. I have to develop a multi-platform application (android and ios) using Ionic (angular framework). Is there any plugin that can help me? I’ve seen that the ‘cordova-background-plugin’ library is not for me because it does not allow me to communicate with the device in the background when the app is closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an Android Service with Phonegap? (Have phonegap app run even when closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos)

Comment: Yes thank u, do you suggest to proceed with ionic framework or native programming ?

Comment: I suggest native due to the background / Bluetooth requirements. Probably not possible to due multiplatform for your use case due to [iOS Bluetooth background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34117336/295004)